# 1st Yr Probability: Independence of flipping a fair coin twice

Tags: probability

**Background**

This is the most simple and basic example of independence.

But unsurprisingly I am having issues with it due to brain shortcomings.

- You flip a fair coin twice
- $X =$ # of heads in the first flip (Bernoulli)
- $Z =$ # of heads in both flips (Binomial)

**My problem**

- It makes sense to me that $X$ and $Z$ are dependent. If you know $Z=0$ then $X=0$
- Let's create a new random variable $Y = Z - X$
- Now if you started off by defining $Y = $ # of heads in the second flip, then it's super clear to me that  $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Knowing the outcome of the first flip doesn't say anything about the second flip
- But if you define $Y$ as $Z - X$ then it is less clear to me that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, because we established that $Z$ and $X$ are dependent and $Y$ has $Z$ in it
- It's weird to me that $X$ and $Z$ are dependent but $X$ and $Z-X$ are independent

Can you explain (pedantically so I understand) where I'm going off the rails?

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Let $X_1 = X$ be nr of heads on first toss and (independently) let $X_2 = Z- X$ be nr of heads on second toss.

Comment: Thanks Bruce that helps. I think my hang up is in naming conventions. When looking at $Z-X$, clearly this "depends" on $X$ because $X$ is the second term of that equation. But if you define it the way you did, then that confusion from naming goes away... I think that is right...

Comment: Okay okay I think I get it. To calculate $Z - X$ you need to use $X$. For example $2-1 = 1$. So $Z-X$ depends on knowing what $X$ is to calculate. But then you look at what it can evaluate to; $Z-X$ can be either $0$ or $1$. But knowing this does not tell you the distribution of $X$ alone. So they are independent. Because if $Z-X = 1$ or if $Z-X = 0$ then either way $X$ can be $0$ or $1$ with equal probability and you have not gained information of what $X$ is alone. Even though to calculate $Z-X$ you clearly need to know $X$.

Comment: _Functional dependence_ does not imply _stochastic independence._ Example: For random normal sample sample mean $\bar X$ and sample variance $S^2$ are stochastically indep, even though $\bar X$ appears in defn of $S^2.$ This fact important in knowing that t statistic has t dist'n. [Not true for non-normal data: for exponential data $\bar X$ and $S^2$ highly correlated; for data from BETA(.5,.5), $\bar X$ and $S$ have $\rho = 0$, by symmetry, but easy to show not indep.] ...

Comment: ... For normal dta indep of $\bar X$ & $S^2$ messy to show in gen'l, but for $n=2,$ $\bar X$ is fcn of $X_1 +X_2$ and $S^2$ is fcn of $X_1 - X_2.$

Comment: Thanks again Bruce. What you said: "Functional dependence does not imply stochastic independence" is the most interesting thing I heard today so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the coins are unbiased:

If you know $Z-X=0$ then you may have either $\{X=0, Z=0\}$ xor $\{X=1, Z=1\}$ with equal probability.

If you know $Z-X=1$ then you may have either $\{X=0, Z=1\}$ xor $\{X=1, Z=2\}$ with equal probability.

So knowing what $Z-X$ equals does not provide any information about what $X$ *alone* may equal.   Thus $X, Z-X$ are pairwise independent.

---

However, knowing any one of the three does provide information on what values the other may jointly be.   $X, Z, Z-X$ are jointly dependent.

Comment: Hmmm that helps... $Z-X$ can either be zero or one with equal probability and it doesn't depend on $X$ alone. This is interesting... $Z-X$ definitely "depends" on $X$ since it's right there in the equation. But it doesn't depend on $X$ "alone"...

Comment: Another question... is this by chance a general property? If an event $X$ is contained in $Z$ then is $X$ and $Z-X$ always independent?

Comment: No. When $Z$ is the sum of independent random variables $X,Y$, then $X,Z-X$ will be independent, *because* $Z-X$ *is* $Y$ .  Which is to say that is $X,Y$ are *not* independent, then $X,Z-X$ will clearly not be independent.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Weird compliment, but you make excellent use of italics.